# Looping element is outside container from conditional

Tags: swift, loops, package

I'm playing with John Sundell's Publish package, and want to try loop over the publish date, and customise the output.

Though Publish package themed, the code is very normalised to Swift.

In essence imagine I have an array of `posts` with the following data:

```swift
let posts = [
  Post( date: 2020-01-01 ),
  Post( date: 2020-01-02 ),
  Post( date: 2021-01-01 ),
  Post( date: 2022-01-01 ),
  Post( date: 2022-01-02 ),
  Post( date: 2023-01-01 )
]
```

I want to loop over the array so that it outputs the year of the post, and then *if* the next post is the same year don't output the year. If it is different then output the year of the new value.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
2023    Post title 1

2022    Post title 1
        Post title 2

2021    Post title 1

2020    Post title 1
        Post title 2
```

So every time the year matches the previous one printed, skip it - otherwise print it out.

The code I was working with so far is:

```swift
func output(posts: [Posts]) -> Node { // where Node is a Publish element
  var currentPostYear = 0
  var savePostYear = 0
  return forEach(items) { item in
    currentPostYear = getItemYear(from: item.date)
    if( savePostYear == currentPostYear ) {
      return .h3( .text(item.title))
    } else {
      savePostYear = currentPostYear
      return .section(
        .h2( .text( "\(getItemYear(from: item.date))" ) ),
        .h3( .text(item.title))
      )
    }
  }
}

func getPostYear(from date: Date) -> Int {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
  return Int( dateFormatter.string(from: date) ) ?? -1
}
```

At the moment because the two different `return` parts of the conditional, I have one `.h3` element within the `.section` while the others are not.

Is there a way I can edit the above to have it so that all the posts within that year are inside the same `section`?

Code view (current):

```html
<section>
  <h2>2023</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>2022</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
</section>
<h3>Post title 2</h3>
<section>
  <h2>2021</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>2020</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
</section>
<h3>Post title 2</h3>
```

Code view (expected):

```html
<section>
  <h2>2023</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>2022</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
  <h3>Post title 2</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>2021</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>2020</h2>
  <h3>Post title 1</h3>
  <h3>Post title 2</h3>
</section>
```

Comment: The issue is that you’re starting and ending your section within the same iteration: the one that introduces an item for a new year. Try using `Dictionary(grouping:posts, by: { getItemYear(from: $0.date) })`. You get a dictionary of posts, grouped by their year. You can then just loop over that, and make one section per iteration (which now represents the entire year with all its posts, rather than a single post)

Comment: In a less optimized way, you could use `Dictionary.grouping(by: thePostYear)`, then iterate over it to return a section with h2 being the year, and h3 for each title.